# NSWindow makeKey() in macOS not working

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

In my menu bar app, I have a menu item which opens a window. The window opens in the front with the window behind it remaining the key window.

I can't get `window.makeKey()` to work unless I run it after a breakpoint. I tried putting the line of code in different places in the window's life cycle and even put it in `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: execute:)` and it didn't work.

I have also tried  using `window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender:)`. The property `window.canBecomeKey` is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I needed to put this line in the IBAction for the menu item that opens the window:

`NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)`

That makes it the key window when it opens, so I don't have to call `window.makeKey()`